# I have a deadlock on a distributed transaction in a .NET 8 environment, but I don't understand how to resolve it

Tags: c#, sqlconnection, distributed-transactions, .net-8.0

I have created a console application using the .Net 8 environment and there is this code in `Program.cs`:

```cs
TransactionManager.ImplicitDistributedTransactions = true;
var transactionOptions = new TransactionOptions();
transactionOptions.IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;
transactionOptions.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3600);


using (IDbConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection(infocitiConnectionString))
using (IDbConnection connection2 = new SqlConnection(storageConnectionString))
{
    TransactionScope ts = null;
    try
    {
        ts = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, transactionOptions);
        {

            connection1.Open();
            //connection1.Execute(sql: sqlDelete);
            connection1.Close();

            connection2.Open();
            //connection2.Execute(sql: sqlInsert);
            connection2.Close();

            ts.Complete();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        ts?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I get a deadlock on the code line:

```cs
ts?.Dispose();
```

[image: Deadlock Schema]

I searched the internet and the net 8 source code but found nothing clear

If I comment out the `ts.Complete();` code, the deadlock disappears.

Comment: _.Close()_ is not needed, cause it is already in a using statement. And the _try finally_ can also be replaced by a third using statement. After this it should work. (Reason: You close the connection before disposing the transaction)

Comment: Have you tried it with all three blocks (try-catch-finally)?
Maybe there is an exception before you reach `ts.Complete()`

Answer (score 0):

I updated the Microsoft.Data.SqlClient package from version 2.1.5 to last actual version(5.1.2) and the deadlock went away